Rigid bodies interacting incorrectly
Im attempting to drop a sphere on a turbo compressor wheel and i want the sphere to "roll" down the fin it hits. instead, when it falls its like it hits an invisible box that's near the comp wheel and shaped differently. Both are set to rigid body. sphere is active+dynamic. Comp wheel is passive+animated+convex hull. Bakes have been deleted. Pulling my hair out on this one. Blender file in google drive here - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zhvlhD4nIpycrLnSardnUnzUsUVIx4kS?usp=sharing 

Please don't make your questions depend exclusively on others downloading the file, or reading links, just to understanding the issue. Please use the [edit] option at the bottom of your question (https://i.sstatic.net/vHwEx.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add images that might help others understand your scene and settings.

You need to set comp wheel to Mesh, not Convex Hull, otherwise the concave shapes of the object won't be taken into account. Convex Hull creates a kind of envelop around the object.

congrats to be the absolute #1 here....!

Hey thanks, I hope Gandalf3 will keep sleeping    ;)

i am sure he will ;)
